# How to set the resolution of a saved image from the UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller, scale

I'm using an UIImagePickerController to set a picture from my cameraroll to a UIImageView. However the image is getting scaled automaticly inside this UIImageView because I mentioned 'scale to fit' inside the IB. I'd like to save my chosen image with a resolution of 80x80 pixels so that I won't have to scale. (My App is getting realy slow because of this scaling issue.)

Here's a snippit from my code:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
      didFinishPickingImage : (UIImage *)image
                 editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
        photoView.image = image;


        NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];       
        NSString *pngFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/foto1.png",docDir];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];

        [data writeToFile:pngFilePath atomically:YES];
}
```

Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can try to edit your image within the delegate method and then save to album. And Most important thing you have to do is "Accept some Answers"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this code here: [Link](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/5204-resize-image-high-quality.html)

```
//  ==============================================================
//  resizedImage
//  ==============================================================
// Return a scaled down copy of the image.  

UIImage* resizedImage(UIImage *inImage, CGRect thumbRect)
{
    CGImageRef          imageRef = [inImage CGImage];
    CGImageAlphaInfo    alphaInfo = CGImageGetAlphaInfo(imageRef);

    // There's a wierdness with kCGImageAlphaNone and CGBitmapContextCreate
    // see Supported Pixel Formats in the Quartz 2D Programming Guide
    // Creating a Bitmap Graphics Context section
    // only RGB 8 bit images with alpha of kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst, kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst,
    // and kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast, with a few other oddball image kinds are supported
    // The images on input here are likely to be png or jpeg files
    if (alphaInfo == kCGImageAlphaNone)
        alphaInfo = kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast;

    // Build a bitmap context that's the size of the thumbRect
    CGContextRef bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(
                NULL,
                thumbRect.size.width,       // width
                thumbRect.size.height,      // height
                CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef),   // really needs to always be 8
                4 * thumbRect.size.width,   // rowbytes
                CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef),
                alphaInfo
        );

    // Draw into the context, this scales the image
    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, thumbRect, imageRef);

    // Get an image from the context and a UIImage
    CGImageRef  ref = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);
    UIImage*    result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref];

    CGContextRelease(bitmap);   // ok if NULL
    CGImageRelease(ref);

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with [Sabobin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578921/how-to-set-the-resolution-of-a-saved-image-from-the-uiimagepickercontroller?answertab=active#tab-top) is that it screws up with the image orientation.

I've found [this solution](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/1164-rotate-uiimage-help.html) that solves the orientation problem and has a faster performance:

```
- (UIImage *)scaleAndRotateImage:(UIImage *)image {
    int kMaxResolution = 320; // Or whatever

    CGImageRef imgRef = image.CGImage;

    CGFloat width = CGImageGetWidth(imgRef);
    CGFloat height = CGImageGetHeight(imgRef);

    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
    if (width > kMaxResolution || height > kMaxResolution) {
        CGFloat ratio = width/height;
        if (ratio > 1) {
            bounds.size.width = kMaxResolution;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width / ratio;
        }
        else {
            bounds.size.height = kMaxResolution;
            bounds.size.width = bounds.size.height * ratio;
        }
    }

    CGFloat scaleRatio = bounds.size.width / width;
    CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(CGImageGetWidth(imgRef), CGImageGetHeight(imgRef));
    CGFloat boundHeight;
    UIImageOrientation orient = image.imageOrientation;
    switch(orient) {

        case UIImageOrientationUp: //EXIF = 1
            transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored: //EXIF = 2
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.width, 0.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0, 1.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationDown: //EXIF = 3
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored: //EXIF = 4
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, imageSize.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1.0, -1.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored: //EXIF = 5
            boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
            bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.height, imageSize.width);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0, 1.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 3.0 * M_PI / 2.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeft: //EXIF = 6
            boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
            bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, imageSize.width);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 3.0 * M_PI / 2.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored: //EXIF = 7
            boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
            bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI / 2.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationRight: //EXIF = 8
            boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
            bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.height, 0.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI / 2.0);
            break;

        default:
            [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException format:@"Invalid image orientation"];

    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bounds.size);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    if (orient == UIImageOrientationRight || orient == UIImageOrientationLeft) {
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, -scaleRatio, scaleRatio);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -height, 0);
    }
    else {
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, scaleRatio, -scaleRatio);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -height);
    }

    CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform);

    CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imgRef);
    UIImage *imageCopy = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return imageCopy;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can resize the selected image using ImageHelper class.

Comment: Do u have a link to the documentation?